# If a sequence converges against a point in a Hilbertian subspace, does it converge in the sense of the topology of this subspace?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with scalar product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_H$ and orthonormal basis $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$. $H$ is a Hilbertian subspace of some space $L$ endowed with $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_L$, i.e. the map $id:H \to L$ is continuous. Hence, any sequence converging to some $h$ in $H$ also converges to $h$ in the sense of the topology defined by the inner scalar product of $L$. $(\tilde a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ with $\tilde a_n = \sigma_n a_n$ with $\sigma_n >0$ is an orthonormal system in $L$.

Now the question: Let $h \in H$. Does $\sum_{i =1}^n \langle h, \tilde a_i \rangle_L \tilde a_i$ converge against $h$ in the sense of the topology defined by $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_H$ as $n \to \infty$? Does the answer change if the map $id$ defined above is additionaly injective?

Comment: Your problem is very simple once you clarify what is a basis and what is "converges against"

Comment: @blamethelag I specified the basis to be an orthonormal basis and tried to make clearer, what converges against means. I mean I can write any $h \in L$ as  $h = \sum_{ n \in \mathbb N} \langle h, \tilde a_n \rangle_L \tilde a_n$ but on the right hand side the sum converges in $L$ and a sequence converging in $L$ does not necessarily converge in $H$.

Comment: @LostinSpace Context: $H$ is an RKHS and Hilbertian subspace of $L_2$. I want to proof $\langle f,g \rangle_H=\sum \langle f,a_n\rangle_L \langle a_n,g\rangle_L \sigma_n$, but my proof only works if the answer to my question is yes. I am new to functional analysis and confused with having to deal with elements in the same space with different scalar products. I find very little on Hilbertian Subspaces (nothing but a work of Xavier Mary, where I can find something useful to me). It seems clear to me that the sum can't converge against something that is not $h$.

Comment: An orthonormal *system* in $\ L\ $ is not necessarily an orthonormal *basis* for it. The dimension of an inner product space can also be *uncountable*, in which case no countable set of its elements can be an orthonormal basis for it. Presumably, you're assuming that the dimension of $\ L\ $ is countable and that $\ \big\{\tilde{a}_n\big\}_{n=1}^\infty\ $ is an orthonormal *basis* for it, not merely an orthonormal *system* in it.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera I don't think I am assuming that the dimension of $L$ is countable and that $\{\tilde a_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a basis for it.
I am assuming, that $\{\tilde a_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal system in $L$ and an orthonormal basis of the closed subspace $\bar H \subset L$. And since any $h \in H$ is (of course) in $\bar H$, I can write $h=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle h, \tilde a_i \rangle_L \tilde a_i$. Is that wrong?
To clearify: With $\bar H$ I mean the closure of the $span(\tilde a_1, \tilde a_2, \ldots)$ wrt. the topology defined by $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_L$.